# Rails 5 and Coffeescript: On Click Event Not triggering

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

On my webpage, I have a div element that is dynamically appended to my page.

In that div I have a link that when clicked, it pulls down data from my server using ajax.

```
<div class="main-div">
  <a href="#" class="pull-data"><b>Click Here</b></a>
</div>
```

If I have an on click event in jQuery on the page, it works fine:

```
$("a.pull-data").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("Clicked!");
}
```

However, when I try converting this to coffeescript, like so, nothing gets triggered:

```
jQuery ->
  $("a.pull-data").on "click", ->
    console.log "Clicked?"
```

Is there something missing in my coffeescript? How can I fix my coffeescript to get it to capture a click on a dynamically added element?

Answer (score 0):

Your two code examples are not equivalent:

```
$("a.pull-data") // create a jquery object matching the CSS selector
  .on("click", function(e) { // add a click handler that
    console.log("Clicked!"); // logs "Clicked!" to the console
  });
```

and here is the transpiled version of your coffeescript:

```
jQuery(function() { // pass anon fn to jQuery constructor
  return $("a.pull-data").on("click", function() { // returning a fn that
    return console.log("Clicked?"); // attaches the click handler
  });
});
```

which is creating an anonymous function that does all the stuff you want and then passing it to the jQuery constructor, meaning it does nothing because its never actually called.

Always, always, ***ALWAYS*** look at your output JavaScript whenever there's a problem. You can even use the interactive compiler at [coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/) to build up functions while keeping an eye on the output.